# Enviando Email de uma aplicação C#

Tags: c#, envio-de-email

É possível realizar o envio de um email direto da aplicação *C#* sem que seja necessário utilizar um servidor? Se sim, como fazer isso?

Por exemplo, no caso do usuário esquecer a senha e eu querer mandar uma nova senha direto do Email, como é possível fazer isso direto da aplicação utilizando *Windows Forms* ou *WPF* em C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não me engano, você precisa de um servidor **SMTP**, acredito que na internet tenham alguns gratuitos.

Agora, supondo que você já o tenha, é bem fácil fazer o envio de emails:

```
//Instanciando a classe "MailMessage" 
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

//Adicione os emails que você vai mandar a mensagem
mail.From = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");
mail.To.Add("email2@hotmail.com");

//Conteudo do email
mail.Subject = "Eu sou o assunto =)"; //Assunto
mail.Body = "Eu sou o corpo do email, sou mais importante =D"; //Corpo do email

//Enviar o email
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Lembre-se de usar o namespace `System.Net.Mail`.